# Ruby on rails nginx , unicorn, capistrano vps hosting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

Hi I am learning how to deploy rails application in VPS, I have followed https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha this tutorial, and everything worked well, I got some errors and corrected them by searching the net, and all works correctly capistrano deploys the files and folders to VPS and if I am changing any code then after type cap deploy it will changed in VPS also, everything works fine there is no error shown in terminal, But the problem is the nginx server is not running (at initial stage it shows its index page -welcome to nginx), I dont know where may be ther problem occurs and what I have to do any  help will be appreciated ,,I am using rails 4.1.4, ruby 2.1.2, capistrano (2.15.5) if its matters..

I dont know which code has to be shown here If you want to see any code I am eager to show you....This is my nginx.conf file

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.projectname.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/administrator/apps/testvps/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
   expires max;
   add_header Cache-Control public;
   }

   try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
   location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
   client_max_body_size 20M;
   keepalive_timeout 10;
 }
```

This is the error I got while `nginx -t` in VPS terminal

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log"            failed     (13: Permission denied)
2014/08/01 15:40:35 [warn] 5682#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2014/08/01 15:40:35 [emerg] 5682#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Paste your `nginx.conf` file content in your question

Comment: yeah done it Raj, while seeing my nginx folder in vps IN sites-enaled there is one link file for nginx.conf file in rails application but if I am click that one it says link brocken

Comment: okay.. let me know output of `nginx -t` command. Run it on server terminal

Comment: Posted the command I got form terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per error shown by `nginx -t`, user don't have permission to write into nginx log files.

Try running `nginx -t` as root user `sudo nginx -t`, if still it shows permission error then try updating permissions:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx;
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx;
```

**Edit:**

As per our discussion, your nginx configuration is successfully set. Now you are seeing blank page while accessing the app.

You need to add `root` to your `routes.rb` file. Rails 4 don't have `public/index.html` file . So, you are seeing blank page. After setting `root` you will be able to see your home page.

Your further doubt:

> so this is nginx.conf file
>   root /home/administrator/apps/testvps/current/public;
>
> shall i change like this:
>   root /home/administrator/apps/testvps/current;

No, nginx should look to your `public` directory of the app. it's rails responsibility to navigate the request to `root_path` as mentioned in `routes.rb`

Comment: I have executed your codes in my server ,still the same error whether I need to restart my server?

Comment: Try `nginx -t` again and paste error (if any) in comment. If no error, then restart the server

Comment: I have executed your codes in my server ,still the same error whether I need to restart my server? –

Comment: okay.. try restarting... Let me know if error is again about permission of `/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Restarting the nginx services also says failed

Comment: which command you are using to restart the server? Lets move to the SO chat for further discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58480/discussion-between-raj-and-navinspm).